# Greetings, signatures, taglines - do we want them in posts?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

On Stack Overflow, greetins, signatures, taglines, etc. are discouraged and are usually removed (edited out) from posts. The main reasons are that they take space and put too much emphasis on the author of the question as opposed to contents. See more details in here: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Is there a policy for that on the Japanese Language site? If not, do we want to follow the same policy as Stack Overflow? Or do we want to make Japanese Language more personal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We should follow the general SO guidelines and remove them from posts. It's been discussed to death in the original meta post, but I think the points are just as applicable here. We're not just another forum, and we're not Yahoo answers. Admittedly we don't have as much of an issue with it here, I think owing mostly to the fact that we have much less traffic, but greetings are still mostly superfluous and signatures redundant. By keeping posts clean and concise we can more effectively maintain the high standard of professionalism and clarity that people have generally come to expect from SE.

Comment: May I add also that up until now editing greetings and signatures out of posts has been common (if not the norm).

Comment: Thanks. I'm quite new here so I couldn't know. I also thought that it would be good to have a question about it on meta for future reference.

Comment: Sure, no harm in getting something formal for discussion!